# How to resolve characters in a UTF16 LE file which causes reading problems in Java 8?

Tags: java, unicode, sed

**Context**: Ubuntu 14.04, Java8

The `file` command reports that my source file is a utf16-le. I can verify that it contains the BOM via hexdump. Thus I chose to use `StandardCharsets.UTF_16` as argument into Apache's commons-io [LineIterator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html) The problem is that when it the code calls:

```
lineIterator.next()
```

on a particular line, it throws an exception.

I used `sed -n 788776p filename` to print out the line. hexdumps shows that it contains the bytes `\x00\x1a` (Unicode U+001A) and also U+0019 & U+001C. Note that sed prints a question mark for U+001A and boxes with their codepoints for U+0019 & U+001C. From your cursory glance, is this caused by the U+001A character ? Or perhaps the other two ? Is this a corruption due to the export process of the file or is this a programming issue with my choice of encoding?

Comment: i guess sed is not using the same character code page (i have the same problem on cygwin sed on file name in a windows environnement). Do you test with other tools like awk  ? (seems that a `p` is missing in your sed command). Normaly a sed to print 1 line on a huge file is not a good issue for performance (prefere a `tail +788776 | head -1` by exemple) and put a `;q` after your `p` if this is no part of a bigger ser action list

Comment: Thanks. I will give awk a try. Yes I missed the p. But the bigger issue is how these unicode codepoints can cause `LineIterator` to fail.

Comment: 1. If you get an exception, you should post the contents of the exception. Normally, encoding related exceptions tell you what’s wrong. 2. If you use Java-8 you can use `new BufferedReader(reader) .lines().iterator()` to get a line iterator without using 3rd party classes. If your question is not about a specific Java-8 feature, tag it with `java` rather than `java-8`.